# Android AsyncTask waiting/queued

Tags: android, android-asynctask, queue, wait, runnable

I have a class extending an AsyncTask that sends messages to a WCF web service. Simple messages one by one will work fine, but if I send a message on a new thread that takes 30 seconds to complete, then midway through that I send a quick request it won't execute the AsyncTask until the long one has returned.

I thought the whole idea of AsyncTask was these two messages would run on different threads and therefore wouldn't stack?

Here is my code:

```
private class RunnableTask extends AsyncTask<RunnableObj, RunnableObj, RunnableObj> {
    @Override
    protected RunnableObj doInBackground(RunnableObj... params) {
        try {
            if (params[0].requestBody != (null)) {
                params[0].request.body(new JSONObject(params[0].requestBody));
            }

            params[0].request.asVoid();

            return params[0];
        }
        catch (Throwable e) {
            params[0].handler.onFailure(e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(RunnableObj runnableObj) {
        super.onPostExecute(runnableObj);

        runnableObj.handler.onSuccess();
    }
}
```

This is my AsyncTask above.

```
public void put(final String urlStr, final String requestBody, final HttpResponseHandler httpResponseHandler) {
    RunnableObj obj = new RunnableObj();
    obj.handler = httpResponseHandler;
    obj.request = webb.put(urlStr)
            .header(ServiceConstants.SessionTokenHeader, MyApplication.getSessionToken())
            .ensureSuccess();
    obj.requestBody = requestBody;

    new RunnableTask().execute(obj);
}
```

This is the method I use to call the Async.

As you can see in the method I use to call the service, I initialise a new instance of RunnableTask each time.

How it performs:

- The long request will go to the web service and start it's 30 seconds of doing things.
- 10 seconds later my quick little PUT creates it's object, then the last thing the debugger shows is the break point on the "new RunnableTask().execute(obj);" line and then it just disappears.
- 20 seconds later the first line of my RunnableTasks doInBackground method will hit and it will perform the PUT.

Please can someone help? Or at least tell me I'm doing something very stupid..

Comment: You should read up a little in the docs about what the purpose of an AsyncTask is. It is not a generic thread where each thing you do is separated off into separate threads. It represents a single task, performed  off the UI thread, which reports results back to the UI thread. So if you put multiple web requests in a single AsyncTask, they will still be executed in order, one after another. To get them executing concurrently, you would need separate AsyncTasks for each request.

Comment: Is that not what I'm already doing since I'm not reusing the same instance of the AsyncTask. How would you suggest I manage this then? A handler maybe? Or possibly Java Threads?

Comment: Well maybe I'm a little unsure about how you are doing this from just looking at your code. Are you running 3 separate requests in 3 separate AsyncTask objects, or are you trying to execute 3 requests in a SINGLE AsyncTask object?

Comment: I'm using the same class 'RunnableTask' for each call but every one is separate and creates a new instance of it.

Comment: Ah ok, that clears things up. See my answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can execute multiple AsyncTask by using executeOnExecutor

```
 if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB ) {
    new MyAsyncTask().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR);
} else {
    new MyAsyncTask().execute();
}
```

For more check the [AsyncTask documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [AsyncTask Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html):

> When first introduced, AsyncTasks were executed serially on a single
>   background thread. Starting with DONUT, this was changed to a pool of
>   threads allowing multiple tasks to operate in parallel. Starting with
>   HONEYCOMB, tasks are executed on a single thread to avoid common
>   application errors caused by parallel execution.
>
> If you truly want parallel execution, you can invoke
>   executeOnExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor, Object[]) with
>   THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR.

As you can see, AsyncTasks currently only operate on a single background thread, meaning multiple queued tasks will have to fire one after another. If you would like to execute concurrent tasks, you'll want to follow the instructions above.